# Как получить отправленный массив методом POST?

Tags: javascript, php, массивы

Есть скрипт:

```js
 $('body').on('click', '[name="update_cart"]', function() {

            //взять данные из формы
            var form = document.getElementById('form');
            var form = document.forms.namedItem("form");
            var formData = new FormData(form); 
                 
            let arr = new Array();
            
            //проверить в консоли
            for (var p of formData.entries()) { 
                var total = arr.push(p[0], p[1]); 
                
            };

            const arrs = new Map([
                [arr[0], arr[1]],
                [arr[2], arr[3]],
                [arr[4], arr[5]],
                [arr[6], arr[7]],
                [arr[8], arr[9]],
                [arr[10], arr[11]]
            ]);

            //ajax
            //Создадим объект для отправки AJAX запроса
            var HttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
            //Функция в которую возвращается ответ от сеовера
            HttpRequest.onload = function(e) {
            //Проверка что результат отчета успешный (может быть 404 или другие)
            if (this.status == 200) {
                
                console.log(arrs); 
                console.log(arr); 
                //Записываем цифру в элемент корзины в верстке
                document.getElementById('chart-value').innerText = this.response;
                //console.log(form);
                
            } else {
                alert('Ошибка');
            }
            };
            //Настройка запроса для отправки (второй параметр путь к PHP скрипту)
            HttpRequest.open("POST", '/cart/', true);
            //Отправка запроса на сервер
            HttpRequest.send(arrs); 
             
            
        });
```

На выходе у него массив "arr" передается на сервер методом POST, сам массив выглядит следующим образом:
[image: МАССИВ]

Так вот, как в файле cart мне этот массив то встречать? пробовал вот так но безуспешно:

```html
$id = $_POST['id'];//Получаем из глобального массива $_POST id товара
$name = $_POST['name'];//Получаем из глобального массива $_POST id товара
$kol = $_POST['kol'];//Получаем количество
$kol2 = $_POST['kol2'];//Получаем количество
$price = $_POST['price'];//Получаем количество
$bouquet = $_POST['bouquet'];//Получаем количество
```

По хорошему мне нужно присвоить переменным значения из этого массива по ключам

Comment: ты просто открой в отладчике `$_POST`   и посмотри что прислал...... да или банально в браузере в панели разработчик во вкладке Network посмотри что отправил

Comment: не знаю, правильно ли я понял задачу...тем не менее взгляните.

Comment: и по хорошему можно было бы приложить какой-нибудь `print_r($_POST)` или еще что-нибудь такое...а то не совсем понятно с чем приходится иметь дело. там возможно вложенные массивы. если так, то их нужно будет привести к адекватному виду

Comment: print_r($_POST) пустой почему то или там выводится Array. А хотя там не принт а echo использовал, может по этому

Comment: @Егор, приложите `print_r($_POST)`... `echo` я не просил... это другое

Comment: Да, вот что он даёт Array
(
)

Comment: Может я не так отправляю?? Потому что посмотрев в панели разработчика во вкладке Network, 
в принципе как и в print_r, показывает что ничего не уходит то кроме какого то пустого массива, а вот если отправлять  вот так "HttpRequest.send(formData);" то там все видно что отправляет. Может перед отправкой как то его нужно сконвертировать или упаковать?

Comment: Попробуйте так заполнить данные для отправки`var data = {}; for (var p of formData.entries()) {  data[p[0]]=p[1]; };`

Comment: и потом `HttpRequest.send(data); `

Comment: И как оно?.. пробовали то, что я в комментарии писал?

Comment: ДА, вот прям только что попробовал все это дело, но опять мустой массив на выходе выдает. print_r($_POST) = Array ( )

Comment: приложите саму форму потом, пожалуйста чтобы я мог потом протестировать сам

Comment: И еще нашел один нюанс, когда товара в корзине два то на выходе получается тоже один массив, дело в том что он по очереди записывает данные и данные с одинаковыми ключами перезаписывает, в итоге получается массив созданный только для последнего товара в корзине. В принципе если оправлять formData, тоже самое и получается, я поэтому и начал формировать отдельный массив что бы их отправлять по отдельности.  Не понял какую форму вы просите приложить

Comment: Пример верстки страницы  на которой расположен и работает ваш скрипнт. С тестовыми данными разумеется (можете сначала накликать тестовых данных, потом забрать готовый пример прямо из брайзера...только в текстовом виде)

Comment: это, чтобы те, кто отвечают банально могли сами протестировать ваш скрипт

Answer (score 0):

Допустим у нас есть массив `$_POST`

```
$_POST = [
    'id' => 1,
    'name' => 'Егор',
    'kol' => 2,
    'kol2' => 3,
    'price' => 1250,
    'bouquet' => 15
];
```

И его можно будет извлечь в переменные следующим образом:

```
extract($_POST);
```

> extract — Импортирует переменные из массива в текущую таблицу символов
> https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.extract.php

После чего будут доступны следующие переменные

```
extract($_POST);
// извлекли из POST следующие переменные:
// $id, $name, $kol, $kol2, $price, $bouquet

// пример использования извлеченных переменных
echo "id: $id \n";
echo "name: $name \n";
echo "kol: $kol \n";
echo "kol2: $kol2 \n";
echo "price: $price \n";
echo "bouquet: $bouquet \n";
```

вывод

```
id: 1
name: Егор
kol: 2
kol2: 3
price: 1250
bouquet: 15
```

См: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.extract.php

Comment: у него будет что-то другое, а не массив) массив массивов, или массив объектов